# jquery don't run same function twice on the same time

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've got a code.

```
setInterval(somefunc, 1000);

function somefunc() {
    curid = $(".chat-message:last").attr("id");
    $.post("http://blah.com/blah.php&last_msg_id=" + curid, function (data) {

        $('.chat-messages').append(data);
    });
}

function saveChat() {
    var texts = $('#chatText').val();

    var request = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://blah.com/submit.php",
        data: {
            text: texts
        },
        dataType: "html"
    });

    request.done(function (msg) {
        somefunc();
    });
}
```

The problem is that sometimes saveChat is executed at the same time as interval and the information somefunc appends to .chat-messages duplicates. How could I avoid it? I need a function which allows to execute function somefunc() again only when previous execution of somefunc() is completely finished. Or just not to allow execute function somefunc() twice at the same time.

Comment: I think it would be better to reconsider your concept.

Comment: In javascript, nothing happens at the same time, it is single threaded.

Comment: but jquery is not fast enough to append data before somefunc starts again..

Answer (score 5):

Don't use `setInterval`, but nest `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout(somefunc, 1000);
function somefunc() {
    //snip
    $.post().done(function () { setTimeout(somefunc, 1000); });
}
```